# Replace redundant emails as unique in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have some redundant email addresses in my SQL Server table with the same name appearing in multiple rows.

I want to append a digit in the email so that their emails become different.

How can I do this?

Comment: For example abc@gmail.com appearing two times in table becomes abc@gmail.com and abc1@gmail.com

Comment: "same name appearing in multiple columns." is a bit confusing. Can you please add the table structure with some sample data and the expected end result.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I am sorry, I meant to say same email name appearing in multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) function to identify subsequent duplicates then prepend the row_number, something like this;

```
declare @t table (email varchar(100))

insert @t values ('pete@abc.org'), ('jane@xyz.org'), ('fred@test.com'), ('pete@abc.org')


select
    case 
        when row_number() over (partition by email order by email) > 1 
        then cast(row_number() over (partition by email order by email) as varchar(32)) + '_' + email
        else email 
    end as email
from
    @t
```

Comment: your solution will not work if the input data is 
_insert @t values ('pete@abc.org'), ('jane@xyz.org'), ('fred@test.com'), ('pete@abc.org'),('2_pete@abc.org')_

Comment: @ughai You are right, but this what the OP asked for. If the OP wants to refine the question I'll review this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate using row_number() in a derived table and add the index to the Email using stuff().

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  Email varchar(100)
);

insert into @T values
('abc@gmail.com'),
('abc@gmail.com'),
('abc@gmail.com'),
('cba@gmail.com');

update T
set Email = stuff(T.Email, charindex('@', T.Email), 0, cast(T.rn as varchar(11)))
from (
     select T.Email,
            row_number() over(partition by T.Email order by T.ID) as rn
     from @T as T
    ) as T
where T.rn > 1;

select *
from @T;
```

Result:

```
ID          Email
----------- ------------------
1           abc@gmail.com
2           abc2@gmail.com
3           abc3@gmail.com
4           cba@gmail.com
```

If you are worried that the new email will become duplicates of already existing emails you can do the update in a loop until there are no more duplicates.

```
while exists (
             select null
             from @T as T
             group by T.Email
             having count(*) > 1
             )
begin
  update T
  set Email = stuff(T.Email, charindex('@', T.Email), 0, cast(T.rn as varchar(11)))
  from (
       select T.Email,
              row_number() over(partition by T.Email order by T.ID)  as rn
       from @T as T
      ) as T
  where T.rn > 1;
end;
```